# Is it possible to create a VPN to a domain (Domain specific VPN) instead of a IP Address in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is there any way to create Domain specific VPN in GCP?
Currently, I am able to create VPN only binding IP address.

Answer (score 0):

In GCP you can only bind a VPN tunnel using IP address. If you are interested in DNS resolution over a VPN you may be interested in DNS forwarding[1](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/overview#dns-forwarding).
Keep also in mind that this feature is still in Beta.

---